# Python - Calculation that generates array in exponential scale

Tags: python, memory, exponential

The logic is to find the average price (and the mode) of a currency where each day (cycle) a fixed percentage is applied to each price of the previous sequence of prices, increasing the value and another fixed percentage reducing the value, generating two new values for each price of the previous sequence.

**To exemplify**:

For a 4 day cycle and starting price: 5.5

*calculation:*

day 1: 5.5 -> 5.5165, 5.494505494505495

day 2: 5.5165 -> 5.533049499999999 5.510989010989011

day 2: 5.494505494505495 -> 5.510989010989011 5.489016478027469

day 3: 5.533049499999999 -> 5.549648648499998 5.527521978021977

day 3: 5.510989010989011 -> 5.527521978021977 5.50548352746155

day 3: 5.510989010989011 -> 5.527521978021977 5.50548352746155

day 3: 5.489016478027469 -> 5.505483527461551 5.483532945082387

day 4: 5.549648648499998 -> 5.566297594445498 5.544104543956043

day 4: 5.527521978021977 -> 5.544104543956043 5.521999978043934

day 4: 5.527521978021977 -> 5.544104543956043 5.521999978043934

day 4: 5.50548352746155 -> 5.521999978043934 5.499983543917633

day 4: 5.527521978021977 -> 5.544104543956043 5.521999978043934

day 4: 5.50548352746155 -> 5.521999978043934 5.499983543917633

day 4: 5.505483527461551 -> 5.521999978043935 5.499983543917634

day 4: 5.483532945082387 -> 5.499983543917633 5.478054890192196

so on...

buy, on day 4 the prices array is:
[5.56629759 5.54410454 5.54410454 5.52199998 5.54410454 5.52199998
5.52199998 5.49998354 5.54410454 5.52199998 5.52199998 5.49998354
5.52199998 5.49998354 5.49998354 5.47805489]

And the mean price is: 5.522044044024749

**My code**:

```py
import numpy as np

days = 4
up = 1.003  # PERCENT_UP
down = 1.001  # PERCENT_DOWN

array = np.zeros((2, 2 ** days), dtype=np.float64)
array[0][0] = 5.5  # STARTING PRICE

for i in range(1, days + 1):
    s = 0
    if i == 1:
        g = 1
    else:
        g = (2 ** i) - 1
    for pos in range(0, g, 2):
        array[1][pos] = array[0][pos - s] * up
        array[1][pos + 1] = array[0][pos - s] / down
        s += 1
    array[0] = array[1]

print(f'For {days} days, all prices: {array[1]}')
print(f'mean price: {np.mean(array[1])}')
```

The problem is that the process for more than 30 days is extremely slow (practically endless). The question is: Is there another **more efficient** way to perform this calculation?

Comment: Unfortunately, concurrency isn't a good candidate here because future results depend on previous results. I think that dealing with the memory issue, i.e. the 2x1073741824 matrix, is going to help with your runtime issue. Consider storing only the values you need for the next computation. For a 2x1073741824 matrix of `np.float64` you need ~69GiB memory available. I bet this code is causing the system to swap, a lot.

Comment: This might be suited to code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Faster way to get that average:
`5.5 * ((up + 1/down) / 2) ** days`

And the mode:
`5.5 * (up / down) ** (days // 2)`
(Only for even number of days, for odd number of days there are two modes, which you'd get by `* up` and `/ down`.)

Comment: Yes that's true, however, I also need to find the most recurring value (mode) in the last array.

Comment: @Apitta That's not in the question.

Comment: @Apitta Added mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Nothing better than a formula! But actually I wanted to find a better logic for this kind of problem where the input of the next loop of array grows exponentially! But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Apitta Unclear what you mean with "better logic" and "this kind of problem". And it's not really exponential. I mean, sure, you get 2^n values, but they're really just n+1 *different* values, massively duplicated. No point building an exponential-size array then, with the same few values repeated over and over again. At most I'd build a `Counter`.

Comment: I mean a better code in python to return a list with the values! Maybe with binary tree, I don't know!

Comment: @Apitta I don't see why you'd want that list. It's just wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to build the array that appear to be ~100 times faster. Benchmarked with 20 days, times shown in seconds, three rounds:

```
True 1.6741721630096436 original
True 0.022637605667114258 Kelly1
True 0.01650857925415039 Kelly2

True 1.6044209003448486 original
True 0.009995222091674805 Kelly1
True 0.01716303825378418 Kelly2

True 1.566394329071045 original
True 0.00938725471496582 Kelly1
True 0.01589202880859375 Kelly2
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVTBjpswEL37K0baw9pZQoB0e4jEodqm1apSGqWpeogiZCUmRQVjGWhLV/vt6dgQILtJj0WRYsbvzbw39qDq8nsup8fjXsTwSaRp7dOi5Lp0YM/rwoFK4Sr/JdmMAD4cQpDK5Vrzmm4scouAslYixHic5rx8@4ZZbJxriCCRoLk8CGrytVkGmTT/KVKKi12eVpmMMOXuB6UcRrY0h0lTnjU5tSgrLYET0gkO/qNg7mqhBC9pwPr4ZjYLtjAKsfQg6NvoJLRiLmjPdXJIJE//rd7Ibhz8ETovKA0cCGA0snB2zYilbbwt/pBsC5DOYdI79JuycAf@wGiBHK97S2JkhCH4PcA8BwT5XUSkhXi9T63ShMF4ADUSVF70IjwHDmiKnfMbC/52g1hjorNkuGPA2GjY75cUY@kybdIfSG/4bmjmxOno/vbs/E4xEldyZ5p1OkqnnaD2PyDEth4R9@49wA18Wb9brR8XH2G5enyYE9v7EAKPVMq00/W8qYEt56uH@WIdfV0So7Xd8odb7z9/WxCSZCrH/LLKVA28wGtCYp1nUCaZgHbTrAkRv5XYGSVWM5q7cu3IixmYtsdiwrEJW35/VKWHOU0Jys4GJb6WvyP6r4k3oHQiSxrffsByT4b63CbgaWo2d6KYwRN/vr1EygSXDQgxOBLmnXI2BDdQ/LrghW5awlxMTXGSUNAY7TgQu1EkeSaiqOftRYpz22dgx@Nf)):

```
def Kelly1(start, days, up, down):
    a = np.array([start], dtype=np.float64)
    for _ in range(days):
        a = np.ravel(np.column_stack((a * up, a / down)))
    return a

def Kelly2(start, days, up, down):
    a = np.array([start], dtype=np.float64)
    for _ in range(days):
        a = a.repeat(2)
        a[::2] *= up
        a[1::2] /= down
    return a

def original(start, days, up, down):
    array = np.zeros((2, 2 ** days), dtype=np.float64)
    array[0][0] = start

    for i in range(1, days + 1):
        s = 0
        if i == 1:
            g = 1
        else:
            g = (2 ** i) - 1
        for pos in range(0, g, 2):
            array[1][pos] = array[0][pos - s] * up
            array[1][pos + 1] = array[0][pos - s] / down
            s += 1
        array[0] = array[1]
    return array[1]

funcs = original, Kelly1, Kelly2

start = 5.5  # STARTING PRICE
days = 20
up = 1.003  # PERCENT_UP
down = 1.001  # PERCENT_DOWN

import numpy as np
from time import time

expect = funcs[0](start, days, up, down)
for _ in range(3):
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        a = f(start, days, up, down)
        t1 = time()
        # print(f'For {days} days, all prices: {a}')
        # print(f'mean price: {np.mean(a)}')
        print((a == expect).all(), t1 - t0, f.__name__)
        del a
    print()
```